# How to make an localhost tunnel not expired after a long time idling?

Tags: ssh, putty, tunnel

Currently I am trying to configure for a tunnel to stay alive aka. **ssh.localhost.run** after idling for a while.

I have do some research and find out this type of **~/.ssh/config** file like this:

```
Host *
     ServerAliveInterval 60
     ServerAliveCountMax 5
```

But after a while (usually 1 hour) PuTTY will respond "Signature from Server's host key is invalid." and old tunnel terminated, I have to make a new tunnel manually, I still **can use** the old key, but tunnels link (domain) is different.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN4g1.png]

My question:

Is there any way that I can keep this tunnel valid (never expires) or any way to resolve that "Signature from Server's host key is invalid"?

Comment: How do your settings compare with [these ones](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-configure-timeout-on-ssh-client-putty/)?

Comment: I have not checked it, I will see it when I got back to my office, BUT this is to keep the session alive, can it keep the same tunnel alive or just create new one after a specified time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't idle expiry – the response is caused by a periodic *re-handshake* that most SSH clients and servers initiate every few hours to exchange new keys. The process is very similar to what happens during the initial connection, including re-verifying the server's "host key" (as a side effect, not as a goal), and apparently your server is doing the re-handshake incorrectly.

In other words, it's a problem with the custom SSH server software that your tunnel is using. (Though, first make sure you have the latest version of PuTTY (i.e. 0.77), in case it happens to be a client bug.)

PuTTY lets you adjust or disable the key re-exchange parameters in "Connection > SSH > Kex". The default time interval is 60 minutes and the default data limit is 1 GB transferred – PuTTY will start a rekey every time *either* of those limits is hit.

With modern ciphers, you can safely increase the rekey periods (hourly rekey was meant for ancient 64-bit or even 56-bit ciphers), e.g. time-based rekey could be set to a week or even disabled entirely, while data-based rekey could be set to something like `1024GB` or disabled as well.

However, this only adjusts client-initiated rekey – it cannot prevent the *server* from requesting a rekey.

Finally, ~/.ssh/config is for OpenSSH – it is not read by PuTTY. The same settings exist in PuTTY but have to be configured through its own settings screens.

Comment: hi, thank you for your help, now I have understand the concepts of re-handshake, however, when I try to adjust Kex to 1 min to check the change, it doesn't do any change tho (I'm using localhost on my own PC), is there any settings that I should look into ?

Comment: for clearer explaination, I have adjusted Kex to 1 min and run ssh.localhost.run again, the Domain still on, thus no "Signature from Server's host key is invalid" pops up, BUT after 1 min I turn off session and re-opened sessions again, I get a new tunnel.